# Getting NullPointerrException while using RollingSink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using windows* plateform. I am reading messages from kafka and want to store in files using RollingSink. I am getting messages but when I add rolling sink to DataStream it throws Null pointer exception. Below are the Code and the stack Trace.
It is creating the folder structure but no data int it.
i.e
Folder 2016-07-13--2031 and three files in this folder
._part-0-0.in-progress.crc, _part-0-0.in-progress, _part-0-0.pending

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment sev = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataStream<String> kafkaStream = sev.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<String>("test", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

    String basePath = "C:\\project\\IOT\\testData\\SinkData";       
     RollingSink<String> rollingSink = new RollingSink<String>(basePath);
     kafkaStream.addSink(rollingSink);


07/14/2016 00:48:48 Job execution switched to status FAILED.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:717)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:663)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:663)
    at `enter code here`scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:401)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1680)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$5.hasNext(FileSystem.java:1733)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.RollingSink.open(RollingSink.java:339)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:38)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:215)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```